# Reducible to Separable First Order Differential Equation Word Problem in Analytic Geometry 1.4-29

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I completed near all problems om a differential equations text chapter on reducing non-separable first order differential equations to separable by using an appropriate substitution for example $u = y/x$ with $y' = u + u'x$ and similar substations in $y$ and $x$ for making other similar problems separable.

I am not asking anyone to do the entire problem for me but I do need a little guidance to begin tackling this problem. I completely understand the procedure for making them separable. What I need help in is setting up the differential equation for the following word problem. Once this is done I can easily finish the problem.

Ch 1.4-29. Show that a straight line through the origin intersects all solution curves of a given differential equation $y = g(y/x)$ at the same angle.

Comment: $y'=g(y/x){}{}{}{}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that the line $y = mx$ intersects a solution to $y' = g(\tfrac{y}{x})$ at the point $(x_0,y_0) = (x_0,mx_0)$. The slope of the line is $m$ and the slope of the tangent line to the curve at $(x_0,mx_0)$ is $y' = g(\tfrac{mx_0}{x_0}) = g(m)$. Based on this, can you figure out the angle between the line and the curve? Does this depend on the value of $x_0$? If not, then the line $y = mx$ intersects all solution curves at the same angle.